# Stamping two rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, lidar, snapping, resolution

I have two LiDAR datasets; one of 1m resolution and another of 2m resolution. I want to stamp 1m LiDAR data on 2m LiDAR.

Similar tool is available in Vertical Mapper in MapInfo called as Splicer where they have an option of stamping two rasters.

Is there any way of stamping two rasters in QGIS?

Comment: When you mention  "LIDAR dataset", I suppose you mean "**altimetric raster layer**, created from LIDAR point data" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Resampling` tool in the processing toolbox\Raster\General tool
and choose the CellSize parameter value to '2'.

[image]